# Same interface for different type and data

Tags: list, haskell, types, interface, algebraic-data-types

So I would like to make some sort of interface for my different `type` and `data` objects. So I have

```
data Tile = Tile {
  coord :: Coord,
  fixed :: Bool,
  wiel :: Bool
  } deriving (Show)


type Source = (Coord , Bool)
type Sink = (Coord , Bool)
```

And would like to make a global interface for all of these, so I want the interface to have another field with `rotating :: Bool` and then the `Tile` or the `Source` or the `Sink`.

Something like if they where to all implement the same interface so they have that extra field. This way I could also put them in a list together which I also need. (Maybe even a `Nothing` option just in case there isn't anything there when I traverse the list).

I tried first doing it without the extra field like this

```
data newInterface = Source | Sink | Tile | Nothing
```

However this doesn't work since I get the error *" `Tile` defined multiple times "*.

How would I be able to solve this ? Thx

Comment: Why do you need them in a list together? Are you sure you need that?

Comment: I want to make a 2 D grid full of these objects for a game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of, you only really have two type definitions here, since both `Source` and `Sink` are just weak aliases. You'd need to use `newtype` to differentiate between them:

```
newtype Source = Source (Coord, Bool)
newtype Sink = Sink (Coord, Bool)
```

Then, there's the [Existential Typeclass Antipattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/):

```
class CommonInterface where
    rotating :: Bool
```

And accompanying implementations:

```
instance CommonInterface Tile where
    rotating (Tile _ x _) = x

instance CommonInterface Source where
    rotating (Source (_, x) = x

instance CommonInterface Sink where
    rotating (Sink (_, x) = x
```

And now for the "meat" of that antipattern, which makes it possible to create a "heterogenous" collection:

```
newtype Anything = forall a. CommonInterface a => Anything a

instance CommonInterface Anything where
    rotating (Anything a) = rotating a
```

Of course, you should, at this point, read the linked article and understand why this approach isn't exactly the best. That being said, for an antipattern it seems to work quite well.

---

Of course if you want to simply have one datatype that encompasses all of the above, that's far easier:

```
data Anything = AnythingSink Sink | AnythingSource Source | AnythingTile Tile | AnythingNothing
```

The implementation of `rotating` then simply has to be done for all possibilities:

```
rotating :: Anything -> Bool
rotating (AnythingSink ...) = ...
rotating (AnythingTile ...) = ...
```

This is far simpler because it requires *all possibilities to be known beforehand*; in the existential approach, you can add more types fulfilling `CommonInterface` without prior knowledge about them.

Answer (score 3):

You can rename your type with a constructor like:

```
data NewInterface = Source | Sink | T Tile | None
```

You cannot use Nothing because it is used by `Maybe` data type

> Edit

The `rotating` part is covered by the answer provided by @Bartek Banachewicz, I was about to edit but his answer covers all.

Answer (score 3):

I think I would do it this way, factoring out the parts of the data that are special to each kind of entity from the common parts:

```
data Entity
    = Tile Bool -- the wiel field
    | Source
    | Sink

data LocatedEntity = LocatedEntity
    { location :: Coord
    , fixed :: Bool
    , rotating :: Bool
    , entity :: Entity
    }
```

No fancy existential types needed (plus you get to avoid their antipattern!), no big case analysis needed at every call-site just to pull out the common fields. Nice and lightweight.

If for some application you need it to be possible for there to be no `LocatedEntity`, you can use `Maybe LocatedEntity` to model that as needed.